# iOS: Is it possible to customize the "Open in..." menu when previewing a document?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm looking to leverage either `UIDocumentInteractionController` or `QLPreviewController` to preview both PDFs and images inside my application. I'm wondering if any of the following customizations are possible (I've scoured the documentation without any luck).

- Remove the "Open in..." menu completely (e.g. the user can preview an image but can't export it to a different application)
- Have the "Open in..." menu open a file OTHER than the one being previewed (e.g. the preview is of a PDF document but the "Open in..." menu will actually export an ePub file)

`UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` has a method `documentInteractionController:canPerformAction:` which seems similar to what I'm looking for, but the documentation indicates that `copy:` and `print:` are the only supported selectors.

(Also, less important, but is it possible to modify the `UIModalTransitionStyle` or `UIModalPresentationStyle` of either a `UIDocumentInteractionController` or a `QLPreviewController`? Since `QLPreviewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, I figured I'd be able to set the modalTransitionStyle and modalPresentationStyle properties, but this didn't yield the desired results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked a few times before and it doesn't seem like much customization is allowed. However, it does seem possible to add an extra UIBarButtonItem to a UIDocumentInteractionController (second link below). As for custom transitions, if you've tried modalTransitionStyle and modalPresentation style then I'm going to assume you can't. I can't find any information about it, but I could always be wrong.

[Can I hide the Action button on the UIDocumentInteractionController view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117119/can-i-hide-the-action-button-on-the-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-view)

[Custom "Email" action in UIDocumentInteractionController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670158/custom-email-action-in-uidocumentinteractioncontroller)

[UIDocumentInteractionController adding custom actions to menu (eg email, save to photos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204911/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-adding-custom-actions-to-menu-eg-email-save-to)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the level of customization that I wanted by showing the QLPrevieController as a child controller, being able to change the parent as pleased.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.previewController];
```