# IOS opening PDF

Tags: ios

I am trying to open PDF file into my application with a custom `UIBarButtonItem` into the `UINavigationBar`, two options to open pdf into `IOS`

```
-UIDocumentInteractionController
-QLPreviewController
```

in `IOS6` i have found this posts with prove that we cant customize the `UINavigationBar`

[Custom navigationItem button with QLPreviewController in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568504/custom-navigationitem-button-with-qlpreviewcontroller-in-ios6)
[QLPreviewController remove or add UIBarButtonItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957091/qlpreviewcontroller-remove-or-add-uibarbuttonitems)
http://www.cimgf.com/2012/07/11/a-better-fullscreen-asset-viewer-with-quicklook/
[Custom "Email" action in UIDocumentInteractionController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670158/custom-email-action-in-uidocumentinteractioncontroller)

"`iOS6` Update This technique of overriding the `QLPreviewController` will no longer work in `iOS 6`. I have contacted Apple about the situation, but they simply stated that it is no longer supported and it is considered a private API"
is there is any other way to open PDF in `IOS` without Using `UIWebView` and to customize the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want to do with the PDF, but you can open a PDF file from the bundle using some code like this:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDoc;
CGPDFPageRef pdfPage;

NSURL* pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"filename" withExtension:@"pdf"];

CFURLRef urlRef = (__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL;
pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(urlRef);

if (pdfDoc == NULL) {
    // Not good
}

if (CGPDFDocumentIsEncrypted (pdfDoc)) {
    if (!CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword (pdfDoc, "")) {
        if (!CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword (pdfDoc, "password")) {
                        // Not good, document is locked
        }
    }
}

if (!CGPDFDocumentIsUnlocked (pdfDoc)) {
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDoc);
} else {
    pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, 1);
    CGPDFPageRetain(pdfPage);
    // ...
}
```

From this point on the documentations from Apple should help you:

[Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/)

[Core Graphics Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html)