# Can I hide the Action button on the UIDocumentInteractionController view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidocumentinteraction

I wanted to know if I can hide the Action button on the UIDocumentInteractionController so a user couldn't actually open the document in another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works for me well enough:

```
- (BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller   canPerformAction:(SEL)action{
    return false;
}
```

It still shows the button but the popover that appears only has the print form but the print button is disabled.

Comment: I could not get this delegated method to get called.  Any idea what missing?

Comment: @user523234 This method is deprecated in iOS 6. If you use it, the following message gets logged: "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate implements legacy action methods. Please remove them."

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of the UIDocumentInteractionController is to show the user which applications can handle a file and give them a way to 'send' the file to the app they choose. Since hiding/disabling the button would confuse the user, I doubt it is possible (at least not without resorting to undocumented method calls).