# iOS, Objective -C How to Hide/remove UIDocumentInteractionController bar/share button from iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, powerpoint, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

I am showing a powerpoint file via UIDocumentInteractionController (Objective - C). The client needs to remove bar/share button from the navigation bar. I have tried and follow much instruction which I found on Google. But all are not working in my case. 
What I tried:

1. [Hide status bar when using UIDocumentInteractionController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770804/hide-status-bar-when-using-uidocumentinteractioncontroller)
2. [UIDocumentInteractionController remove Actions Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116820/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-remove-actions-menu)
3. [Can I hide the Action button on the UIDocumentInteractionController view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117119/can-i-hide-the-action-button-on-the-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-view)[image]

My Code:

```
 if ([documentType isEqualToString:DOC_TYPE_PPTX]) {


                self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:documentUrl];

                // Configure Document Interaction Controller
                [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

                // Preview PDF
                [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];


            }
```

If not possible to hide/remove this share button then please suggest me another custom library/framework for show powerpoint file without share button in objective - C. Thanks in advance. Any suggestion will be Great.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116820/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-remove-actions-menu

Comment: @ Jamil. This is not duplicate. I have already tried much advice including which you have shared. This is not worked for me including other advice. That's why I have asked this question. Please check my 2nd number URL.

Comment: Finally, I have fixed this issue via webView. My code:


 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.URLLoadOnWebView];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
   
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];